# Django dynamic form for variations products

Tags: django

I have two models for creating dynamic variations for each product, 'ItemVariation' --> e.g. Blue, Yellow, ... and 'Variation' --> e.g. Color, Size,...

```
class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, related_name='variations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('product', 'name')
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ItemVariation(models.Model):
    variation = models.ForeignKey(
        Variation, related_name='item_variations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('variation', 'value')
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

As you can see the variations are dynamic, and I can't figure how to add them to a form and then into view

Comment: Have you looked at `django.contrib.admin.TabularInline` or `django.contrib.admin.StackedInline`. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

Comment: I want this on site, not on the admin page.